# How to set timeout for a cmd command?

Tags: perl, cmd

i just have the following command in cmd

```
perl csv2rrd3.pl
```

but it always run for a long time.
Is there any way to set a timeout for it?
or i should do it in the perl script?? And how?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside of Perl, you can set an [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) to go off after a few seconds. You can then use a signal handler to catch the event. Only one alarm may be active at any time

```
{ # enter new scope
    # set signal handler
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
       # do cleanup, like closing sockets or whatever
       print STDERR "exited with ALARM\n";
       exit;
    };
    alarm 30; # try half a minute
    ...; # do expensive stuff
}
```

Comment: You can use this code inside the Perl script. The part that may take too long to run goes at the place marked with the ellipsis. Or you could write a wrapper script, then you would do a `system` call to the original script; while this is easier, it may be vital for the original script to do some cleanup (tempfiles, connections) before it exits. It would also be a good idea to set the alarm from the commandline. You would then write `alarm $ARGV[0]//30` or similar where 30 is a default value.

Answer (score 6):

From the windows command line, you can first `start` the perl script in its own window, chain it with the `timeout` command to wait *x* seconds (here 2) and then chain it again with the `taskkill` command to kill the process.

```
start perl csv2rrd3.pl & timeout -t 2 & taskkill /IM perl.exe
```

The line above would kill every perl process. To kill only your just started one, you could use a custom window title.

```
start "KILLME" perl csv2rrd3.pl & timeout -t 2 & taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq KILLME" /IM perl.exe
```

Comment: On Windows, you can use [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Process), which has a Wait() method for timeout.

Comment: it shows error that "this process can only be terminated forcefully", and seems the .pl have not been execute yet

Comment: @DannyHo Well, then try it forcefully with `/F`, i.e. `taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq KILLME" /IM perl.exe`. It works for me on Windows 7 Professional SP1.

Answer (score 0):

well, not sure about timeout, but you can wait some specific time and then kill the process.

```
sleep(10) # sleep 10 seconds
kill      # and insert PID of the process (see command ps)
```

Comment: OP asked about `cmd`, which is usually the Windows "shell". It doesn't have `ps` or `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer if PowerShell is available:

The starting, waiting, and killing of the command all hapens within Powershell, making this work for any envrionment, not just Peral.

```
$x = Start-Process -Filepath "ping" -ArgumentList 'google.com -n 100' -NoNewWindow -PassThru; 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; 
try { Stop-Process -Id $x.Id -ErrorAction stop } catch {};
```

Replace *ping* and the argumnets list with whatver needs to run.

If you need an early return (e.g. the process will end **either** when the command finishes **or** the timeout is reached, then replace `Start-Sleep ...` with a loop that checks if $x.Id is still an active process, then sleeps for 1 second if it is.